# Why has my question been considered off topic and deleted?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question about architecture of a front-end application, and it has been closed as off topic, without any explication regarding why it would be off-topic :

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/394248/how-to-fetch-the-same-data-for-multiple-components-in-a-react-app

It's a question about architecture, so maybe it's not well written, but it's definitely on topic, according to the help center.

Could anybody clarify why it's considered "off-topic"?

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak for certainty, but it looks like you understand the architectural direction that you want to go in. The difficulty you are having requires the implementation details in a particular technology stack and framework, which boils down to help writing the code to realize your design. Questions about writing code are off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree because I think there is a step between high-level design and code-specific implementation (namely, detailed architecture) but I get your point. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @gvo: I am not an expert on this technology stack, but it seems the obvious conceptual solution to your question is to introduce your own cache, or a find a library or framework which provides one for those React widgets. From that point on, however, one probably has to dive into the technical details of React.